# How to analyse trend lines on non-uniformly sampled time series data in R?

Tags: r, time-series, linear-model

I have four time series of the same parameter (e.g., air temperature) sampled at four distinct stations.
Because of sampling and logistical issues, the sampling at the four stations were conducted manually by one operator and applying a continuous regular time interval sampling was not possible.
As such, samplings at the various stations are non-continuous and have different time lengths.

Here are two of the four datasets that I am analysing using R:

```
    >ST1


     Date_Time_UTC Air_Temp
 1:    2016-12-24           -26.19000
 2:    2016-12-24           -20.58000
 3:    2016-12-24           -22.69000
 4:    2016-12-24           -27.43000
 5:    2016-12-25           -20.63000
 6:    2016-12-25           -22.26000
 7:    2016-12-25           -22.49000
 8:    2016-12-25           -25.07000
 9:    2016-12-25           -24.95000
10:    2016-12-25           -24.69000
11:    2017-01-15           -25.23000
12:    2017-01-15           -24.81000
13:    2017-01-16           -24.50000
14:    2017-01-16           -23.90000
15:    2017-01-16           -23.72000
16:    2017-01-16           -25.14000
17:    2017-01-16           -23.63000
18:    2017-01-16           -23.47000
19:    2017-01-16           -25.45000
20:    2017-01-16           -25.24000
21:    2017-01-17           -23.71040
22:    2017-01-17           -24.07000
23:    2017-01-17           -21.78000
24:    2017-01-23           -22.80000
25:    2017-01-23           -22.28000
26:    2017-01-23           -22.75582
27:    2017-01-23           -22.82000
28:    2017-01-23           -23.30000
29:    2017-01-23           -21.53000
30:    2017-01-24           -21.21000
31:    2017-02-19           -20.83000
32:    2017-02-19           -22.18700
33:    2017-02-26           -24.13000
34:    2017-02-26           -24.94000
35:    2017-02-26           -23.43000
36:    2017-03-16           -23.56783
37:    2017-03-16           -23.72000



> ST2
> 
    Date_Time_UTC Air_Temp
 1:    2017-01-03           -26.32000
 2:    2017-01-03           -25.87000
 3:    2017-01-03           -26.19000
 4:    2017-01-03           -26.30000
 5:    2017-01-03           -26.30000
 6:    2017-01-04           -25.87000
 7:    2017-01-04           -25.67000
 8:    2017-01-04           -24.73000
 9:    2017-01-04           -25.61000
10:    2017-01-04           -24.09000
11:    2017-01-06           -25.93000
12:    2017-01-06           -24.89000
13:    2017-01-06           -24.64000
14:    2017-01-06           -22.91000
15:    2017-01-07           -22.35000
16:    2017-01-07           -23.98432
17:    2017-01-07           -24.02000
18:    2017-01-07           -25.09000
19:    2017-01-07           -24.81000
20:    2017-01-07           -24.41000
21:    2017-01-07           -24.29000
22:    2017-01-07           -22.26000
23:    2017-01-08           -21.62000
24:    2017-01-08           -19.74000
25:    2017-01-08           -24.75000
26:    2017-01-08           -19.29000
27:    2017-01-08           -19.47000
28:    2017-01-08           -26.20000
29:    2017-01-08           -23.30000
30:    2017-01-10           -26.83000
31:    2017-01-10           -23.10000
32:    2017-01-10           -26.97000
33:    2017-01-10           -24.12000
34:    2017-01-10           -25.83000
35:    2017-01-10           -26.04000
36:    2017-01-10           -22.57000
37:    2017-01-10           -25.80000
38:    2017-01-11           -26.44000
39:    2017-01-11           -24.77000
40:    2017-01-11           -25.53000
41:    2017-01-11           -25.50272
42:    2017-01-11           -26.64000
43:    2017-01-11           -26.19000
44:    2017-01-11           -26.06000
45:    2017-01-12           -25.69000
46:    2017-01-12           -26.76000
47:    2017-01-12           -25.54000
48:    2017-01-12           -27.23000
49:    2017-01-12           -26.55000
50:    2017-01-13           -26.96000
51:    2017-01-13           -26.69000
52:    2017-01-13           -27.00000
53:    2017-01-13           -27.05000
54:    2017-01-13           -28.12000
55:    2017-01-13           -26.88000
56:    2017-01-25           -28.59000
57:    2017-01-26           -27.96000
58:    2017-01-26           -28.84000
59:    2017-01-26           -28.26014
60:    2017-01-26           -27.42000
61:    2017-01-26           -26.80000
62:    2017-01-26           -28.07000
63:    2017-01-27           -31.53000
64:    2017-02-18           -27.21000
65:    2017-02-18           -27.28000
66:    2017-02-18           -28.84464
67:    2017-02-18           -27.19000
68:    2017-02-28           -24.82000
69:    2017-02-28           -24.68000
70:    2017-03-01           -27.93044
71:    2017-03-01           -25.08245
72:    2017-03-01           -24.70034
73:    2017-03-01           -23.09000
74:    2017-03-02           -28.45894
75:    2017-03-14           -26.84184
76:    2017-03-14           -27.08000
77:    2017-03-14           -26.56000
78:    2017-03-14           -26.43000
79:    2017-03-14           -26.91900
80:    2017-03-14           -26.97000
81:    2017-03-15           -26.21000
```

The aim of my analysis is to draw a trend line for my time series data, fitting a regression model that can capture the relationship between the variable and time. My hypothesis is that temperature decrease or increase over time at different stations. What should I do in order to achieve my goal?

Initially, I draw a linear regression using `geom_smooth` with `ggplot` and testing the `lm` function to get slope, R2 and p-value, but I am not sure if this is appropriate for non-uniformly sampled data. I also do not know if I need to test some conditions, such as stationarity, autocorrelation, heteroscedasticity, and/or others.

e.g.

```
formula <-  Air_Temp~Date_Time_UTC
    model <- lm(formula, data = temp_df)
    summary(model)
```

I tried to find online a clear explanation on how to deal with my aim and the type of dataset I have. Unfortunately I did not find a clear explanation. I have the suspicion that I need to test for stationarity and autocorrelation and in case at least one of them is not satisfied it is advisable to use a different model than linear regression, such as the OLS which uses the principle of minimizing the sum of squared errors.

However, I am not sure at all of what I have understood. My knowledge in statistics is very basic.

May you please explain what are the steps and methods that I need to follow in order to draw a trend line on a non-uniformly sampled time series data?
May I use a linear regression model in these conditions in order to show the overall variability of my variable over time?
What are the tests I need to perform and can you suggest an R-script?

Comment: First we need to focus on your data. The first variable is called `Date_Time_UTC`, which indicates that it should contain information regarding the time of the day. But you only show dates, which is a problem since you have multiple measurements per day, which might have been taken at different times and temperature usually exhibits diurnal cycles. Also, you need to know what `Air_Temp` measures: temperature at the specific time point, average, min or max temperature over some period, ...?

Comment: I'm also quite concerned that you seem to believe that OLS regression and the `lm` function in R are fundamentally different approaches. The latter does the former. If this is a serious data analysis and not just homework or for fun, you don't appear to be qualified to do this. I don't believe asking on the internet solves that issue.

Comment: Talking about the "Date_Time_UTC" variable, I apologize for any confusion. In this analysis, the air temperature measurements were consistently observed at the same UTC time each day. The inclusion of time information was not necessary in this analysis, as observations were taken at a fixed time point. As such, while I understand @Ronald 's point about potential diurnal temperature variations, for this analysis, the focus is more on the overall temporal trends rather than the diurnal cycles.

Comment: How can one operator do several measurements at identical time manually? Does the variance of these measurements at identical time points only reflect measurement uncertainty or is there another source of variation?

Comment: Regarding how vital it is to make sure my data analysis is solid and accurate, I'm absolutely committed to doing a proper job here. My stats know-how isn't the strongest, and that's why I'm looking for advice from pros like you. Altough this isn't just a casual thing or a school assignment, I genuinely want to bring valuable insights to the table.
If you could share some tips on the best steps and methods for putting together a trend line on my kind of wonky time series data, and maybe suggest any tests or tweaks that would work well, I'd be super appreciative. Thanks for your help.

Comment: @Ronald, thanks for pointing that out. We went with a simple approach – measuring at midday every day – to tackle the measurement hiccups. Think of these readings as the day's max temperature. It was a way to keep things consistent and avoid the messiness of multiple readings.

Comment: Yes, but why are there several values for the same day?

Comment: First step is always to plot the data. Then I would consider using the `gls` function from package nlme to derive trends. It allows inclusion of an autocorrelation structure in the model, even if the timeseries doesn't have regular timesteps, but you need unique time values (maybe you can calculate means and use the number of replicate measurements as weights).

Comment: I'm also unsure how useful analyzing a trend over a few months could be. That's not even one annual cycle.

Comment: Thank you @Ronald, and I apologize for any confusion.
Regarding the multiple readings for the same days, each station was placed on a moving industrial platform within a specific area where air conditions varied significantly (as shown by the data). We aimed to take multiple readings simultaneously from this moving platform, but at times, instrument limitations or scheduling issues prevented this. As a result, in some days we have a few readings only.

Comment: Originally, I thought of treating these multiple readings as replicates and potentially averaging them. However, I ended up analyzing them individually, assuming a linear regression would consider the highest and lowest values among the replicates. My focus isn't on capturing a complete annual cycle; rather, I aim to highlight changes in temperature from the start to the end of the monitoring period at these stations,  emphasizing the overall temperature shifts observed during the entire monitoring duration.

Answer (score 0):

I'll demonstrate how I would analyze your first dataset for a trend. You first need to consider that your repeated measurements at the same date need to be dealt with because they would overestimate the number of independent observations. One option of doing that could be a mixed-effects model but I think we can also just calculate the means and use the number of "pseudo-replicates" as weights. You can try and add an auto-correlation structure (for continuous data) to the model but the low number of timepoints makes it unlikely to be worth.

If you fit separate models to the stations you need to consider if you might have a multiple-testing issue, i.e., alpha-error inflation. You might want to apply a correction to the p-values. You could try fitting a combined model to all station data but since they cover different time periods that might not be sensible. I can't say without more background knowledge.

```
DT[, Date := as.Date(Date_Time_UTC)]

DTagg <- DT[, .(Temp = mean(Air_Temp), n = .N), keyby = Date]

library(ggplot2)
ggplot() +
  geom_point(data = DT, aes(x = Date, y = Air_Temp)) +
  geom_point(data = DTagg, aes( x = Date, y = Temp, size = n, color = "mean"))
```

[image: plot illustrating the data]

```
#transforming to days since first measurement
#better for numerical precision and for interpretation of coefficients
DT[, time := Date - min(Date)]
DTagg[, time := Date - min(Date)]

fit1 <- lm(Air_Temp ~ time, data = DT)
summary(fit1)
#ignores the repeated measures

fit2 <- lm(Temp ~ time, data = DTagg, weights = n)
summary(fit2)
#same coefficients but degrees of freedom reflect true replicates (i.e., time points)

library(nlme)
fit3 <- gls(Temp ~ time, data = DTagg, weights = varFixed(~ I(1/n)))
summary(fit3)
#same model but with nlme framework

#plot residuals
plot(fit3)

fit4 <- gls(Temp ~ time, data = DTagg, weights = varFixed(~ I(1/n)), 
            correlation = corCAR1(form = ~ time))
#added auto-correlation model
summary(fit4)
#Generalized least squares fit by REML
#  Model: Temp ~ time 
#  Data: DTagg 
#      AIC      BIC   logLik
#  41.9432 42.26097 -16.9716
#
#Correlation Structure: Continuous AR(1)
# Formula: ~time 
# Parameter estimate(s):
#      Phi 
#0.6131893 
#Variance function:
# Structure: fixed weights
# Formula: ~I(1/n) 
#
#Coefficients:
#                 Value Std.Error   t-value p-value
#(Intercept) -23.719957 0.6283355 -37.75047  0.0000
#time          0.005965 0.0161504   0.36933  0.7215
#
# Correlation: 
#     (Intr)
#time -0.783
#
#Standardized residuals:
#        Min          Q1         Med          Q3         Max 
#-1.10329429 -0.64849425  0.02230492  0.96125598  1.29292847 
#
#Residual standard error: 2.047013 
#Degrees of freedom: 10 total; 8 residual

anova(fit4, fit3)
#     Model df      AIC      BIC    logLik   Test  L.Ratio p-value
#fit4     1  4 41.94320 42.26097 -16.97160                        
#fit3     2  3 41.87382 42.11214 -17.93691 1 vs 2 1.930617  0.1647
#auto-correlation not significant
#fit2 can be used --> no significant trend anyway
```